# Different languages for I like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

How do I display the text of the I like button in a different language with HTML5 script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook connect button language change](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9160199/facebook-connect-button-language-change)

Answer (score 8):

When you initialize fb-jssdk

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

change js.src url to your locale

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ and search for "How do I display the Like button in different languages?"